# Denoising with AIDenoiser makes some colors black

Tags: denoise

I'm using Blender 2.83.3
I've set up a denoiser node setup in the compositor.
When I lead the noisy image into the denoiser most of my colors turn black. If I use the original image this doesn't happen.
Below you can see my node setup, the "before" denoising pic, and the after denoising pic.

Any ideas?

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Good Pic]

[image: Bad Pic]